# Bash Script printing different output of same command running on "cmd line window" and "reading from csv file"

Tags: bash, shell, csv, eval

I have a shell script which reads input command(with arguments) from a csv file and execute.

The command is `/path/ABCD_CALL GI 30-JUN-2010 '' 98994-01`

here `''` is single quote without space,

In csv file I am using `/opt/isis/infosys/src/gq19iobl/IOBL_CALL GI 30-JUN-2010 \'' \'' 98994-01`
to escape single qoutes

Below is the shell script

```
IFS=","
cat modules.csv | while read line;
do 
d="${line}"
eval "$d"
done
```

This command shows hundreds of records as an output on console window.

The issue I am facing is, the same command when I type manually and run from command window, I am able to see all the output records; but the same command when I am running from csv using shell script mentioned above I am getting only 1 record which shows error array.

I applied debugging using

```
set -x
```

trap read debug

There I can see below output

```
+ cat modules.csv
+ read line
' d='/path/ABCD_CALL GI 30-JUN-2010 '\'''\'' '\'''\'' 98994-01
' eval '/path/ABCD_CALL GI 30-JUN-2010 '\'''\'' '\'''\'' 98994-01
++ /path/ABCD_CALL GI 30-JUN-2010 '' '' $'98994-01\r'
------------- ABCD RESULT SUMMARY -------------
ABCD return message :  MESSAGE ARRAY must be checked for ERRORS and WARNINGS.  and ABCD returned a 1
Total balances : 0.

Total errors : 1.
error_array[0]
```

and so on with other details of error.

What should I do to see the same output when reading the same data from csv?

Comment: I don't see why you need to escape the quotes in the CSV file.

Comment: Escaping the quotes passes them literally to the `ABCD_CALL` program, but it should just get an empty string.

Comment: and I don't know why, in debugging mode, with last value "$" in starting and "\r" at the end always showing., You can see it in my last comment also

/path/ABCD_CALL GI 30-JUN-2010 '' $'98994-01\r'

Comment: I though quotes may be creating problem, and not using the command from csv file as it is, But you are right If I don't use escape characters also I am getting below lines in command window 

' d='/path/ABCD_CALL GI 30-JUN-2010 '\'''\'' 98994-01 ' 

eval '/path/ABCD_CALL GI 30-JUN-2010 '\'''\'' 98994-01 

++ /path/ABCD_CALL GI 30-JUN-2010 '' $'98994-01\r'

Comment: It's really hard to read things like that in comments. Add it as an update to the question.